# convert slash to division

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a column of type character which looks like (1/1), (2/3), (4/5) etc.

I would like to convert this to a vector like 1, 0.66, 0.80 etc.

Is there a simple way to do this?

The only way I could think of would be something like

Pseudocode

```
separate string delimited by slash, as part[1] and part[2]
part[1] = as.integer(part[1])
part[2] = as.integer(part[2])
score = part[1]/part[2]
```

EDIT :
My data looks as follows

```
> df[1:10,"score"]
 [1] "1/1" "1/1" "3/3" "1/1" "1/1" "4/4" "1/1" "2/2" "4/5" "4/5"
> class(df$score)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of your data? Do you actually have parenthesis in each entry?

Comment: Try `eval(parse(text='2/3'))` or for the vector, `sapply(gsub('[()]', '', v1), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))`

Comment: @akrun I was sensing someone will suggest that, though it is not vectorized and you''ll need something like `sapply(c("1/1", "2/3", "4/5"), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))` and someone will probably add a comment soon that it is thrown upon and etc.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, please see edit above.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, you are right and using `eval(parse` may not be optimal

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg and akrun, I used
df$inthelpfulness = sapply(df$helpfulness, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is your data

```
x <- c("1/1", "1/1", "3/3", "1/1", "1/1", "4/4", "1/1", "2/2", "4/5", "4/5")
```

using `read.table`

```
with(read.table(text = x, sep = "/"), V1 / V2)
## [1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.8
```

Or as per @akruns comment, using `scan`

```
temp <- scan(text = x, what = numeric(), sep = "/", quiet = TRUE)
temp[c(TRUE, FALSE)]/temp[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
## [1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.8
```

Or using `strsplit`

```
temp <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "/")))
temp[c(TRUE, FALSE)]/temp[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
## [1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.8
```

Or

```
library(gsubfn)
as.numeric(gsubfn("([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)", ~ as.numeric(x)/as.numeric(y), x))
## [1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.8
```

Comment: Or you could use `scan` `matrix(scan(text=x, what=numeric(), sep="/", quiet=TRUE), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 as.numeric(sub('\\/.*', '', v2))/as.numeric(sub('.*\\/', '', v2))
```